# Why does Windres report a syntax error on my GROUPBOX statement?

Tags: c++, winapi, resources, groupbox

I'm experimenting with the Win32 API in C++, specifically with writing resource files. Now, my entire project was working just fine, menus and titles and everything. However, when I add this code for a modal dialog box to the .rc file:

```
IDD_ABOUT DIALOG DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 239, 66
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "My About Box"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&OK",IDOK,174,18,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Cancel",IDCANCEL,174,35,50,14
    GROUPBOX        "About this program...",IDC_STATIC,7,7,225,52
    CTEXT           "An example program showing how to use Dialog Boxes\r\n\r\nby theForger", IDC_STATIC,16,18,144,33
END
```

Windres exits with the following error:

```
windres: resource.rc:40: syntax error
```

Line 40 refers to:

```
GROUPBOX "About this program...",IDC_STATIC,7,7,225,52
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381014(VS.85).aspx),

> The GROUPBOX statement, which you can use only in a DIALOGEX statement, defines the text, identifier, dimensions, and attributes of a control window.
>
> GROUPBOX text, id, x, y, width, height [, style [, extended-style]]

Their example:

```
GROUPBOX "Options", 101, 10, 10, 100, 100
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still have the same syntax error on the same line after switching to a `DIALOGEX` statement (as @YeenFei pointed out), the only thing I can think of is that `IDC_STATIC` is not defined.

Try changing it to

```
GROUPBOX "About this program...",-1,7,7,225,52
```

If that fixes the problem, it's because the identifier isn't defined.

I did a search through the Platform SDK headers (6.1 and 7.1) and didn't find it. I think that might be an MFC-specific identifier -- some quick Googling suggests MFC defines it in "afxres.h" if it isn't already defined.

`IDOK` and `IDCANCEL` work even though you didn't explicitly define them because they are defined in the Platform SDK (in "winuser.h").

Comment: IDC_STATIC is also defined in winuser.h

Comment: @KenB: Not it's not.  It's a control value that would normally be taken from a project-specific `resource.h`.  See any of the numerous sample programs in the Windows Platform SDK.

Comment: I just used grep and found it defined not only in winuser.h but also in afxres.h.

Comment: I don't know why, but defining IDC_STATIC fixes it for some reason.

Comment: @KenB If you see it in winuser.h, what version of the Platform SDK do you have?  It might have been in an older version.  (I also used grep, and I got no hits at all for the versions I have.)  Maybe the definition in your header file is surrounded by a version check?

Comment: I am using MinGW 4.5.2. Here is what I have concluded upon further examination of the header files.

Winuser.h does indeed have IDC_STATIC documented; however, it is not actually defined because it is surrounded by an #if 0 statement, with a comment noting, "This is supposed to be defined by the program using it not defined in the w32api headers. I've left it here for documentation purposes."

Answer (score 4):

I think it is pretty much self-explanatory from

> can use only in a **DIALOGEX**
>   statement

Comment: Ha, I missed that, thanks. But unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem.