# Why does Windres report a syntax error on my GROUPBOX statement?

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why does Windres report a syntax error on my GROUPBOX statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778823/why-does-windres-report-a-syntax-error-on-my-groupbox-statement)

NOTE: This is a repost from yesterday. I really didn't get an answer for it, and it has fallen behind in the C++ (among others) queue.

I'm experimenting with the Win32 API in C++, specifically with writing resource files. Now, my entire project was working just fine, menus and titles and everything. However, when I add this code for a modal dialog box to the .rc file:

```
IDD_ABOUT DIALOGEX DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 239, 66
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "My About Box"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "&OK",IDOK,174,18,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Cancel",IDCANCEL,174,35,50,14
    GROUPBOX        "About this program...",IDC_STATIC,7,7,225,52
    CTEXT           "An example program showing how to use Dialog Boxes\r\n\r\nby theForger", IDC_STATIC,16,18,144,33
END
```

Windres exits with the following error:

```
windres: resource.rc:40: syntax error
```

Line 40 refers to:

```
GROUPBOX "About this program...",IDC_STATIC,7,7,225,52
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381014(VS.85).aspx),

> The GROUPBOX statement, which you can use only in a DIALOGEX statement, defines the text, identifier, dimensions, and attributes of a control window.
>
> GROUPBOX text, id, x, y, width, height [, style [, extended-style]]

Their example:

```
GROUPBOX "Options", 101, 10, 10, 100, 100
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Windres` is the GNU resource compiler right? The MS resource compiler `rc` handles your resource file just fine.

Comment: I don't see why this is tagged C++, it's purely a Windows API and Windres question.

Comment: Self-admitted duplicate of [Why does Windres report a syntax error on my GROUPBOX statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778823/why-does-windres-report-a-syntax-error-on-my-groupbox-statement) The way to get attention for a question is to edit it to add new information, not to re-post it.

Comment: @David: I'll give that a shot. Also, you're right, I suppose I was just thinking in C++, since this file is part of a C++ project. My mistake.

@Rob: My mistake. Won't happen again.

Comment: Yes, that's defined in <windows.h>.

Comment: @KenB @templatetypedef `IDC_STATIC` wasn't defined for me. I just hard coded an ID 'cos I assumed `IDC_STATIC` was defined by you.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two possibilities:

1. Windres has a bug.
2. Windres has a different spec.

Based on (what at least looks like) the [windres spec](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/windres.html), your code is wrong -- at least as it's shown, you should have a comma on the end of the `GROUPBOX` line (optionally followed by a `params`). My guess, however, is that the comma is really only intended to be there if you also include the `params`.

Of course, it's possible the grammar they give really reflects what windres accepts, even if that wasn't what was really intended. It should be pretty easy to *try* adding a comma, and seeing if it accepts that -- but quite frankly I doubt that'll do any good.

As such, option 2 above is clearly correct, but it's entirely possible that option 1 is as well.